# How can i work with negative and percentage values in css calc? (Fluid Design)

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I found this awesome css [calc function from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/)

```css
calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

I try to use this calc function like this for `margin-right`

```css
margin-right: calc(-20% + (0 - -20) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1600 - 320)));
```

I wanted to achieve the following:

```
-20% at 320px viewport width
0% at 1600px viewport width
```

The css calc function works perfectly with positive values, but apparently not with negative values. How do I change the calc function to work with percentages and negative values?

I tried this

```css
margin-right: calc(-20% + (0% - -20%) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1600 - 320)));
```

but this is invalid.

**Background**

I am using this js function to calculate ranges

```js
function _translateRange(
    input,
    inputMin,
    inputMax,
    outputMin,
    outputMax
) {
    let inputMinA = Math.min(inputMin, input);
    let inputMaxA = Math.max(inputMax, input);

    return (
        outputMin +
        ((outputMax - outputMin) * (input - inputMinA)) /
            (inputMaxA - inputMinA)
    );
};
```

like this

```js
translateRange(window.innerWidth, 320, 1400, -45%, 0%)
```

I want to convert this function to a css calc function. Why? Why do I not use the js function to calculate `margin-right`? Because I want to do without as much js as possible in my application.

Note: This flexibility is especially important for me because I also want to work with as few media queries as possible.

#### Edit

I restructured my css code. I configure my absolute element, so i can use positive px values at begin and end with 0. So in this way, the css calc function works as i aspected.

Comment: `(0% - -20%)` is a percentage size, `((100vw - 320px) / (1600 - 320))` is a px size. You can't multiply these together. Multiplying in `calc` can't have units in both hands.

Comment: you calculate (0% - -20%) i think theres the error. You can shorten the formular down to calc(-40% *((100vw-320px) / (1600 - 320))

Comment: @Raqha thanks but this is also invalid

Comment: [There are better ways to achieve this now](https://css-tricks.com/simplified-fluid-typography/)

Comment: better show your real use case because I am sure the solution is a lot easier than what you think

Comment: @Daniel_Knights thanks I already looked at it, in my case with negative values it does not work, because my minimum value is negative and my maximum value is 0

Comment: I might be calculating wrong but (-20+(0--20) = 0. And 0 * anything is still 0. You cannot divide 0 with anything, so you get an error.

Comment: @J.W thanks, but how can i solve this?

Comment: Try to change your 0% to 1% and see what happens ;-)

Comment: @J.W this `calc(-45% + (1 - -20) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1600 - 320)))` and `calc(-45% + (1% - -20) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1600 - 320)))` is invalid

Comment: Phew, it's getting a lot of math now. Have you considered using clamp instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp

Comment: @J.W doesn't work with negative values like `clamp(-45%, .5%, 0%)` or `clamp(-45%, .5%, 1%)`

Comment: Cant you just do this part in JavaScript? Calculations are a lot, a lot easier there